# chai-assertion to validate anyone is true should pass

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to do assertion to validate any one statement is true, test should pass. Following is the code

> expect(commuication.status).to.contain(
> "PROCESSED",
> "NOT_PROCESSED"
> );

where communication.status return different value out of "PROCESSED""NOT_PROCESSED" values. This assertion throwing me error->Unexpected Undefined. What am i doing wrong here? any help

Comment: Probably `commuication.status` is `undefined`.

Comment: So what is the right way to do this assertion, so that based on the test data is status return processed it will pass and if test data has status=not processed" test still pass

Comment: Your assertion is correct. Fix your code so that `commuication.status` contains one of those values.